# How to subtract matrices from elements of cell arrays in a loop?

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, cell

I have created a cell array of dimensions 1x10, named A. Each element contains a 100x5 matrix. Hence, I got 10 matrices 100x5. However, I want to put every matrix of the cell array into a loop. If B is a 100x5 matrix, C is a 100x1 vector and c is a constant, the loop should look like:

```
 for t=1:100;   
    j=1:5;   
        x=c*inv((B(t,j)-A(t,j))*((B(t,j)-A(t,j))')*(A(t,j)-C(t,1)*ones(1,5));   
    end;   
 end;
```

At the end x should deliver a 1x10 cell array that will contain 10 elements of matrices 100x5.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Since `A` is a cell array, shouldn't you be referencing the cell `A{k}` in there somewhere?  It would also be helpful to post a working example of `A`, `c`, `B`, `C`, and also a mathematical expression of what you are trying to solve.

Comment: So you are saying that it should be like this: for t=1:100;   
    j=1:5;   
        x=c*inv((B(t,j)-A{k(t,j)})*((B(t,j)-A{k(t,j)})')*(A{k(t,j)}-C(t,1)*ones(1,5));   
    end;   
 end;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to access a cell array.  Let `i` index the cell array.  Then you can access the `i`th entry of the cell array by calling `A{i}`.  Then your code is:

```
for i=1:10
    for t=1:100   
        j=1:5  
           x{i}=c*inv((B(t,j)-A{i}(t,j))*((B(t,j)-A{i}(t,j))')*(A{i}(t,j)-C(t,1)*ones(1,5));   
        end 
    end
end
```

You may want to think about your problem and whether or not you can eliminate the the two middle for loops by writing it in matrix notation.  It looks similar to a least-squares estimator, which is `(X'X)^(-1)*X'y`, but the element-by-element inverse is throwing me off.